# Downloading problem at slow internet speeds

Tags: 14.04, firefox, internet

Recently I had very slow download speeds at my home and It was taking 6 hours to download a file of just 250 MB with firefox browser ,So is there any program that I can use to increase my download speeds??

Comment: @Tim- I have got solution and on other os the speed is same as on ubuntu

Comment: yeah that might be a point but what i experienced is that the same file if downloaded with the software which I mentioned in answer rather than with firefox downloaded by 4x (four times) greater speed

Comment: Actually I tried to do so but community says you will need to wait for 2 days to accept your own answer

Comment: Ahh yes, didn't notice you answered it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good tool for this purpose known as Xtreme Download Manager XDM it can boost download speed by 4 Times and the best thing is it is also available for Ubuntu you can download it by typing

```
wget -O xdman.zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdman.zip/download
```

Now unzip the zip file and put it into a folder

```
`mkdir xdman

unzip xdman.zip -d xdman/
```

Enter into Xdman directory and give it execution permission

```
cd xdman/`

chmod +x xdman.sh
```

Finally Run the xdmam.sh file

```
./xdman.sh
```

For more information see [this](http://ubuntuportal.com/2013/04/xtreme-download-manager-alternative-internet-download-manager-for-linux.html)